# I am learning Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, edit

i have created a new and edit functions form my post. The problem i have is the button under edit post reads as "Create Post" instead of "Update post"
Kindly asssist here

Comment: Hi. Could you post some code of what have you done? Specially, controllers and views codes here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails form_for, just try this
replace your

```
<%= f.submit %> with the bellow one,

<%= f.submit 'Update post' %>
```